# Check if size of all elements are the same on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've this code here:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    window.onresize = function() {
        alert("changed");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

What I change the window size now I need to check if one of my childs is higher than the other ones. If true, I want to add a class `wrapped` to all of my childs. How can I do this within JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Please share your attempts.

Comment: @Jeto No attempts because no idea how to do this :)

Comment: Can you at least provide a relevant HTML/CSS sample where things move higher/lower than each other depending on window size?

Comment: Sure, one second please.

Answer (score 0):

check it
if I understand correct

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    window.onresize = function() {
        var winWidth = $(window).width()
        $('.child','.container').each(function(idx,item){
            if($(item).width() > winWidth)
              console.log(item,$(item).index())
        })
        
        alert("changed");
    }
});
```

```css
.child{
width:800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```